# Differentiate gtk.Entry icons

Tags: python, icons, pygtk, gtkentry

I'm adding two icons to a gtk.Entry in PyGTK. The icons signals are handled by the following method

```
def entry_icon_event(self, widget, position, event)
```

I'm trying to differentiate between the two of them:

```
<enum GTK_ENTRY_ICON_PRIMARY of type GtkEntryIconPosition>
<enum GTK_ENTRY_ICON_SECONDARY of type GtkEntryIconPosition>
```

How can I do this? I've been digging through the documentation of PyGTK but there's no object GtkEntryIconPosition nor any definition for this enums.

Thanks

Comment: Well, it seems as I can compare using position.value_name which returns the name of the enum. Also, by creating a new object like:
x = gtk._gtk.EntryIconPosition(0) for PRIMARY
x = gtk._gtk.EntryIconPosition(1) for SECONDARY
And then compare the objects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is better way to do it:

```
def entry_icon_event(self, widget, icon, event):
    if icon == gtk.ENTRY_ICON_PRIMARY:
        ...
    elif icon == gtk.ENTRY_ICON_SECONDARY:
        ...
```

Comment: Cool, I knew there should be a better way to do it. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Alright, since no one gave an answer, I'll do with what I actually found. A method to use this icons would look like this:

```
def entry_icon_event(self, widget, icon, event):
    if icon.value_name == "GTK_ENTRY_ICON_PRIMARY":
        print "First Button"
        if event.button == 0:
            print "Left Click":
        else:
            print "Right Click"
    elif icon.value_name == "GTK_ENTRY_ICON_SECONDARY":
        print "Second Button"
        if event.button == 0:
            print "Left Click":
        else:
            print "Right Click"
```